# Kibana configuration foe es with production and monitoring clusters

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I referred [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.12/settings.html#elasticsearch-hosts) and [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.12/monitoring-settings-kb.html)

Why do we need two fields to let Kibana know where is the monitoring data.

`elasticsearch.hosts`

`monitoring.ui.elasticsearch.hosts`

But when I give my monitoring cluster at either of these properties, it works. I assumed badly that `elasticsearch.hosts` is my actual production cluster than monitoring cluster.

Apart from `why` part, is my understanding correct about this integration attributes?

Any thoughts? Thanks.

**Kibana.yml:**

```
server.host: "ip.ad.re.ss"
#elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://host1:9200","http://host2:9200","FewMoreHosts"]
monitoring.ui.elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://MonitoringNode:9200"]
```

I haven't changed any part in `elasticsearch.yml` of monitoring node.

**metricbeat.yml:**

```
output.elasticsearch:
   host: ["http://MonitoringNode:9200"]

setup.kibana:
   host: kibanaHost
```

In modules.d/elasticsearch-xpack.yml, I left the default configurations.

**elasticsearch.yml:**

```
cluster.name: es_cluster
node.name: master-1
node.data: false
node.master: true
node.ingest: true
node.max_local_storage_nodes: 3
transport.tcp.port: 9300
bootstrap.memory_lock: false
network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9200
discovery.seed_hosts: ["master1.ip", "master2.ip","master3.ip"]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["master-1","master-2"]
```

**Monitoring cluster yml:**

```
network.host: 0.0.0.0
discovery.type: single-node
```

When I enable both properties in Kibana.yml, I get the below error in the log.

```
{
  "type": "log",
  "@timestamp": "2021-04-21T14:48:34-04:00",
  "tags": [
    "error",
    "plugins",
    "data",
    "data",
    "indexPatterns"
  ],
  "pid": 29959,
  "message": "Error: No indices match pattern \"metricbeat-*\"\n    at createNoMatchingIndicesError (/usr/share/kibana/src/plugins/data/server/index_patterns/fetcher/lib/errors.js:45:29)\n    at convertEsError (/usr/share/kibana/src/plugins/data/server/index_patterns/fetcher/lib/errors.js:71:12)\n    at callFieldCapsApi (/usr/share/kibana/src/plugins/data/server/index_patterns/fetcher/lib/es_api.js:69:38)\n    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)\n    at getFieldCapabilities (/usr/share/kibana/src/plugins/data/server/index_patterns/fetcher/lib/field_capabilities/field_capabilities.js:35:23)\n    at IndexPatternsFetcher.getFieldsForWildcard (/usr/share/kibana/src/plugins/data/server/index_patterns/fetcher/index_patterns_fetcher.js:49:31)\n    at IndexPatternsApiServer.getFieldsForWildcard (/usr/share/kibana/src/plugins/data/server/index_patterns/index_patterns_api_client.js:27:12)\n    at IndexPatternsService.refreshFieldSpecMap (/usr/share/kibana/src/plugins/data/common/index_patterns/index_patterns/index_patterns.js:216:27)\n    at IndexPatternsService.getSavedObjectAndInit (/usr/share/kibana/src/plugins/data/common/index_patterns/index_patterns/index_patterns.js:320:23) {\n  data: null,\n  isBoom: true,\n  isServer: false,\n  output: {\n    statusCode: 404,\n    payload: {\n      statusCode: 404,\n      error: 'Not Found',\n      message: 'No indices match pattern \"metricbeat-*\"',\n      code: 'no_matching_indices'\n    },\n    headers: {}\n  }\n}"
}
```

But if I set only monitoring.ui.elasticsearch.hosts, Kibana shows the data.

Answer (score 1):

The `elasticsearch.hosts` is the place where you will set the hosts where your data is stored, the data you want to query, this should be your production cluster.

The `monitoring.ui.elasticsearch.hosts` is the place where you will set the hosts of your monitoring cluster **if** you have a separated monitoring cluster.

Depending on the size of your cluster it is recommended to have a separated cluster just for monitoring, this could be a single-node cluster using the basic license, for example.

Comment: Let's say metricbeat ships data to monitoring cluster which is configured in monitoring.ui.elasticsearch.hosts. And actual production data cluster detail is loaded in elasticsearch.hosts. If I do this, kibana throws error that metricbeat-* not found. If I put that in monitoring.ui.elasticsearch.hosts, it shows metricbeat collection in kibana. That means enabling both are not working. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: For what you described you are not shipping the monitoring data to your monitoring cluster, but to your production cluster. If you put your production cluster in the `monitoring.ui.elasticsearch.hosts` option and you can see the monitoring data, then your monitoring data is not being shipped to the monitoring cluster.

Comment: I tried to keep two clusters. One is production cluster. Another is monitoring cluster. I want all beats data to be stored on monitoring cluster. At the same time, I want to visualize the production data and metrics as well in Kibana. So as you said, when I set elasticsearch.hosts to production cluster, monitoring.ui.elasticsearch.hosts to monitoring cluster, I am getting an error in kibana that metricbeat collection not found. I have not changed the defaults for the collection name. But when I set only monitoring.ui.elasticsearch.hosts to monitoring cluster, it shows metrics in kibana.

Comment: You need to provide more information, update your question with your `metricbeat.yml` file and the `elasticsearch.yml` from both of your clusters. As I said, it seems that your monitoring data is not going to the monitoring elasticsearch cluster.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help. I have added the details. Please check.

Comment: Well, your metricbeat seems to be configured to send to the `monitoringNode:9200`, so it should work having it in `monitoring.ui.elasticsearch.hosts`. Can you check the logs for both metricbeat and elasticsearch in your monitoring cluster? Also, share the complete `elasticsearch.yml` for both of your cluster, this help to see the full picture.

Comment: Yes. Metricbeat sends data to that monitoring cluster. I am able to see metricbeat-* index in the monitoring cluster. I will update elasticsearch.yml too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231442/discussion-between-gibbs-and-leandrojmp).

Answer (score 0):

> The security tokens that are used in these contexts are cluster-specific, therefore you cannot use a single Kibana instance to connect to both production and monitoring clusters

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/monitoring-data.html), I think that we need to have separate Kibana instance to collect data from both clusters.

I am not sure much about the security tokens.